# Deserialize xml file on android studio

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, serialization, deserialization

I wrote an app that uses an xml file I created, and I need to deserialize it to a list. Each item in the list has some properties and an inside list. For example:
     
    `<persons>
        <person>
            <FirstName>fn1</FirstName>
            <LastName>ln1</LastName>
            <Age>30</Age>
            <FavoriteColors>
                <ColorItem>
                    <ColorName>red</ColorName>
                    <IsFavorite>True</IsFavorite>
                </ColorItem>
                <ColorItem>
                    <ColorName>blue</ColorName>
                    <IsFavorite>False</IsFavorite>
                </ColorItem>
            </FavoriteColors>
        </person>
        <person>
            <FirstName>fn2</FirstName>
            <LastName>ln2</LastName>
            <Age>20</Age>
            <FavoriteColors>
                <ColorItem>
                    <ColorName>white</ColorName>
                    <IsFavorite>False</IsFavorite>
                </ColorItem>
                <ColorItem>
                    <ColorName>black</ColorName>
                    <IsFavorite>False</IsFavorite>
                </ColorItem>
                <ColorItem>
                    <ColorName>pink</ColorName>
                    <IsFavorite>True</IsFavorite>
                </ColorItem>
            </FavoriteColors>
        </person>
    </persons>`
 I know how to do it on c#, but I'm new to java and couldn't find a way to do that. What is the best, shorter and easiest way to do that? do I need to build classes for it like in c#? or are there commands to go threw over the xml elements to build my list? is json would be better over xml? if so, how do I deserialize json? Thanks for the helpers! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who need the solution, this is how I solved it. I used dom parser.

First, I created a class for the favoriteColors with its properties.

```
public class FavoriteColors
{
    private String ColorName;
    private boolean IsFavorite;

    public FavoriteColors(String _colorName, boolean _isFavorite)
    {
        this.ColorName = _colorName;
        this.IsFavorite = _isFavorite;
    }
}
```

Then, I created a class for the person with its properties.

```
public class Person
{
    private String FirstName;
    private String LastName;
    private String Age;
    private List<FavoriteColors> AllColors = new ArrayList<FavoriteColors>();

    public Person(String _firstName, String _lastName, String _age, List<FavoriteColors> _allColors)
    {
        this.FirstName = _firstName;
        this.LastName = _lastName;
        this.Age = _age;
        for (int i = 0; i < _allColors.size(); i++)
        {
            this.AllColors.add(_allColors.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

The parse code:
You need to read your xml file to a string (or in any other way you choose) and the final list where all data is collecting to is listOfPersons, which I defined in the code.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String xmlFile = "your xml file"  // read your xml file to string

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try
        {
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlFile));
            Document document = builder.parse(is);

            List<Person> listOfPersons = new ArrayList<Person>();
            NodeList nodeList = document.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();

            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++)
            {
                Node node = nodeList.item(i);

                if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                {
                    Element elem = (Element) node;
                    String firstNameText = "";
                    if (elem.getElementsByTagName("FirstName").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0) != null)
                    {
                        firstNameText = elem.getElementsByTagName("FirstName").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                    }
                    String lastNameText = "";
                    if (elem.getElementsByTagName("LastName").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0) != null)
                    {
                        lastNameText = elem.getElementsByTagName("LastName").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                    }
                    String ageText = "";
                    if (elem.getElementsByTagName("Age").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0) != null)
                    {
                        ageText = elem.getElementsByTagName("Age").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getTextContent();
                    }

                    List<FavoriteColors> listOfColors = new ArrayList<FavoriteColors>();
                    NodeList nl = elem.getElementsByTagName("FavoriteColors").item(0).getChildNodes();

                    for (int j = 0; j < nl.getLength(); j++)
                    {
                        Node n = nl.item(j);

                        if (n.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                        {
                            Element e = (Element) n;
                            String colorName = "";
                            if (e.getElementsByTagName("ColorName").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0) != null)
                            {
                                colorName = e.getElementsByTagName("ColorName").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                            }
                            boolean isFavorite = false;
                            if (e.getElementsByTagName("IsFavorite").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue() != null)
                            {
                                isFavorite = Boolean.parseBoolean(e.getElementsByTagName("IsFavorite").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
                            }

                            listOfColors.add(new FavoriteColors(colorName, isFavorite));
                        }
                    }

                    listOfPersons.add(new Person(firstNameText, lastNameText, ageText, listOfColors));
                }
            }
        } 
        catch (ParserConfigurationException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Hope it will help others. :)